# Dynamic notification from sqlite db

Tags: java, android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I've got a question for you. I want to use a notification service through BroadcastReceiver and AlarmManager. I set the alarm manager with a dynamic list of times from my db.

I use this method that i call on my MainActivity OnCreate(), but doesn't work

```
private void restartNotify() {
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    am.cancel(pendingIntent);
    ArrayList<String> item = new ArrayList<String>();
    item = GetLists.GetTimesListForNotification(this);
    for (int i = 0; i < item.size(); ++i) {
        String time = item.get(i);
        int Position = time.indexOf(":");
        int hour = Integer.parseInt(time.substring(0, Position));
        int min = Integer.parseInt(time.substring(Position + 1));
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                pendingIntent);
    }
```

this is my broadcast receiver

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    NotificationManager mManager;
    mManager = (NotificationManager) context.getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(
                    context.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),
            MainActivity.class);

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            "Nuovo messaggio da cura alert", System.currentTimeMillis());
    intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent1,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context.getApplicationContext(),
            "Le notifiche funzionano", "it is working",
            pendingNotificationIntent);

    mManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

}

Thank you.

Comment: What are the benchmarks you are testing on? Also in your Manifest: `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />` Also are you sure you are getting correct values for your Calendar variables?

Comment: Advisable would be to use `setInexactRepeating` for `API-19` or `setRepeating` instead of `set`. Also you must wake the `CPU` by acquiring a `wakeLock`. Do consider alarms are wiped off after reboot, you must include a `boot broadcast listener` from your `Manifest.xml` Further reading: http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Comment: Not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is because your pending intents request code is same though you are running a loop.  What you can do is get your pending intent intu your loop and set the request code i. This may work. Though it is late but this may help others

Comment: Please elaborate on the answer- ideally with some code snippets.